# Maximum number of Awesomium WebCores can i spin simultaneously?

Tags: c#, awesomium

Using Awesomium version 1.6.6 for Windows, C#.

i'm seeing some strange behaviors after 25 concurrent WebCore objects who browse in parallel to different sites. is there a hard max number of simultaneous WebCores one can use? can this be increased? i'm looking to achieve hundreds if not thousands of parallel browsing sessions based on Awesomium.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that you actually mean `WebView` an not `WebCore` instances? The `WebCore` is a singleton. It is initialized once when your app starts (or when the first view is created) and should be shutdown when your app exits. So there's actually only one `WebCore` per process.

As for `WebView` instances, there is no standard limitation. However limitations may apply based on the client system's resources, given that each `WebView` instance is rendered in a separate, isolated rendering process.

Comment: Yes, I was actually referring to WebView instances. Any official numbers on that?